# how to perform communication between container ViewModel and and contained ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Please consider the following code

```
    class VMContainer:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    Type t;
    VMContained contained;

    public Type T
    {
        get
          {
               return this.t;
          }
        set
          {
               this.t = value;
               this.OnPropertyChanged("T");
          }
    }
    ........
    ........
    ........

    }
```

VMContainer and VMContained are two ViewModel classes. 
Now I need to change one property(say, P1) of member instance "contained" whenever the Container class property T changes.How should I do that?
Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way would just be to set the value in the setter for `T`:

```
public Type T
{
    get
      {
           return this.t;
      }
    set
      {
           this.t = value;
           contained.P1 = CalculateContainedValue();
           this.onPropertyChanged("T");
      }
}
```

**Update**

```
public Type T1
{
    get
      {
           return this.t1;
      }
    set
      {
           this.t1 = value;
           contained.P1 = CalculateContainedValue();
           this.OnPropertyChanged("T1");
      }
}

public Type T2
{
    get
      {
           return this.t2;
      }
    set
      {
           this.t2 = value;
           contained.P1 = CalculateContainedValue();
           this.OnPropertyChanged("T2");
      }
}

private Type CalculateContainedValue()
{
    return /* Some combination of T1, T2, ... */ ;
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your suggestion. As a matter of fact value of P1 is dependent on four properties of VMContainer class. What is the best way to accomplish that? I am thinking of calling a common method(say CalculateVal) from setter section of all four properties of VMContainer class and in that method, set the value of P1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx). Sample is [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/355473/Prism-EventAggregator-Sample).

Else you have to make your own pub sub mechanism.

Comment: if you one VM has another VM then go ahead with Andrew Cooper solution.